# SwiftUI Display JSON Data after GET Request

Tags: json, swift, concurrency, swiftui

I know this is classic concurrency problem, but I'm new to Swift and I feel like I've read through every relevant blog post about this. I know I'm fetching data correctly because it's showing up in my console, but I can't get it to display in my simulator. I believe it's because I'm displaying the UI before the data has loaded.

How can I display the data ***after*** I 100% fetched all the data. I'll add the relevant code and screenshots of the console. Sorry if this is a "basic" question.

[image]

[image]

**Structs**

```
struct Welcome: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int?
    var readings: [Reading]?
    var include_maintenance_recommendations: Bool?
    var pool_volume: Int?
    var created_at, updated_at: String?
}

struct Reading: Decodable {
    var analyte: String?
    var value: String?
}
```

**UI**

```
var results = Welcome()

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var res = Welcome()
    var body: some View {
         Text(results.created_at ?? "N/A")
             .onAppear(){
                fetchResults().getData {(res) in
                    self.res = res
             }
         }
    }
}
```

**Fetch Func**

```
class fetchResults{
func getData(completion: @escaping (Welcome) -> ()){
    print("Fetch")

    let parameters = "{  \"pool_volume\": 10000,  \"readings\": [    {      \"analyte\": \"fc\",      \"value\": 1.6    },    {      \"analyte\": \"ph\",      \"value\": 7.3    }  ]}"
    let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.biolabhydra.com/api/v3/water_tests")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
    request.addValue("Basic ***********************", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("csrftoken=***********************", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, _) in
        let resultList = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data!)
                        print(" ")
                        print("ID: \(resultList.id ?? 111)")
                        print("VOLUME: \(resultList.pool_volume ?? 111)")
                        print("RECOMMENDATIONS: \(resultList.include_maintenance_recommendations ?? true)")
                        print("CREATD AT: \(resultList.created_at ?? "N/A")")
                        print("UPDATED AT: \(resultList.updated_at ?? "N/A")")
                        print("READINGS: \(String(describing: resultList.readings))")
                        print(" ")
        print("SUCCESS: Got data - \(data! )")
    }
    task.resume()
}
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use local property instead of global variable

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var res = Welcome()
    var body: some View {
         Text(res.created_at ?? "N/A")      // << here !!
             .onAppear(){
                fetchResults().getData {(res) in
                    self.res = res
             }
         }
    }
}
```

2. add callback after decoded data

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, _) in
        let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data!)
                        print(" ")
                        print("ID: \(resultList.id ?? 111)")
                        print("VOLUME: \(resultList.pool_volume ?? 111)")
                        print("RECOMMENDATIONS: \(resultList.include_maintenance_recommendations ?? true)")
                        print("CREATD AT: \(resultList.created_at ?? "N/A")")
                        print("UPDATED AT: \(resultList.updated_at ?? "N/A")")
                        print("READINGS: \(String(describing: resultList.readings))")
                        print(" ")
        print("SUCCESS: Got data - \(data! )")
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           completion(result)           // << here !!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a suggestion for the best way (Pod, package, website, etc) to have your JSON data "set up" correctly into structs out the gate versus me assuming I'm setting them up correctly?